# How to remove the default text which appears inside textboxes in forms on android devices?

Tags: android, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have an html5 based mobile app. In the app I have a form for entering userid and password. But in the android device when I take the cursor inside the textbox some default text appears as shown in the image.

[image]

How can this default text be removed?

XML:

```
<label for="username" 
       id="EmailAddress">
</label> 
<input type="text" name="username" 
       id="username" value="" 
       autocorrect="off" 
       autocapitalize="off" 
       autocomplete="off" 
       style="-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;" /> 
<label for="password" 
       id="Password">
</label> 
<input type="password" title="" name="password" 
       id="password" value="" 
       style="-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;" />
```

Comment: have you given value of textbox as "Email Address" or placeholder in inputType??

Comment: You must have assigned placeholder as "Email Address" in input tag.thats why its showing in textbox.

Comment: This is what I am using <label for="username" id="EmailAddress"></label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" style="-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;" />
    <label for="password" id="Password"></label>
    <input type="password" title="" name="password" id="password" value="" style="-moz-appearance:none;-webkit-appearance:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;"  />

Comment: the code seems perfect to me.refresh and try to run again.

Comment: I am running it on my device. The app is live. wish I could share the url with you :'(

Comment: Accept answer using which you have solved.

Comment: I haven't found any answer yet but this doesn't seem to the case on android 4.0. This issue persists in 2.3.x versions only.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about hint, You can set it as `textB.setHint(`"String");

or by setting `android:hint` from textBox xml declaration.

Comment: Thanks man but I am not sure how I can use this using javascript and Html5. I did not developed my app in phonegap/java. Can you please suggest?

Comment: basically you got the idea that it is called hint, Why dont you try to search how hint can be set from html5, Frankly speaking i don't know H of html..:)

Answer (score 1):

YOu give `android:hint`
 property to Edittext at that time this would be appear. Remove it.

Comment: Thanks Hardik but I am not sure about using this as my app was developed solely in html5 using javscript and all the data calls were made through web handlers in C#.

Comment: sorry buddy i dont know about hint in html5.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email Address"
    />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint=" Password "
    android:inputType="textPassword"
     />
```

Comment: How can I do this using javascript/jquery/Css. I am not using phonegap.